# Make command stuck at target

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile for 2 services/subprojects that are webservers. When I run make, it gets stuck on "listening on port 8000" log message from source server and never proceeds to the next target.

```
.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo "source: localhost:8000"
    @echo "status: localhost:5000"
    make -j2 sourcerun statusrun

sourcerun:
    make -C source run

statusrun:
    make -C status run
```

```
# source
.PHONY: run
run:
    @echo "Starting source..."
    [ -d node_modules ] || $(MAKE) deps
    yarn run start

deps:
    @echo "Installing dependencies..."
    yarn
```

```
# status
.PHONY: run
run: venv
    ./venv/bin/python3 main.py

.PHONY: venv
venv:
    @if [ ! -d venv ]; then \
        python3 -m venv venv; \
        ./venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt; \
    fi
```

I was expecting it to run parallelly without getting stuck on first target. Is there a way to parallelize this without detaching from shell?

Comment: How do you imagine two process running in parallel, but at the same time attached to the (same?) shell?

Comment: You need to either use `$(MAKE)` when invoking a sub-make, not `make`, or you need to specify `+` as a prefix to your recipe lines that invoke sub-make.  You should always do the former, though, so the latter is not needed.  Either that or you'll have to use a much higher `-j` value (you could even just leave off the value and say `make -j` with no limit).